# how to get value from input in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with [angular date picker](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker) directive. I would like to get the value of the date that is entered via date picker and console.log it. But somehow everything I have tried so far does not work.

My code:

**HTML:**

```
 <input class="form-control"
       ng-model="ctrl.input"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
       placeholder="Select a date..."
       moment-picker="ctrl.input" id='date'>

    <button ng-model='ctrl.input' ng-click="onclick()">submit</button>
```

**JS**

```
angular
  .module('Demo', ['moment-picker'])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.onclick = function(){
      console.log(angular.element(document).find('#date').val());
    }



  }]);
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/n8HlCN?p=preview)

Comment: Log out the ctrl.input

Comment: why does your button have `ng-model`

Comment: Remove `ng-model='ctrl.input'` from the button element, replace the current console with `console.log($scope.ctrl.input)` (Because I don't think you're using `controller as` correctly - If that's what infact what your actually trying)

Comment: With several usable answers, have a stylesheet so that the calendar is actually readable. Just put this line in your index.html file or wherever you keep your stylesheets.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/css/datetimepicker.css" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're using *controller-as* syntax in your HTML but you haven't defined your controller as such.  You're controller is still using the older $scope-as-controller syntax.
2. Also you had another `ng-model` pointing to `ctrl.input` on your submit button which *could* interfere with things so removed that.
3. As another person stated you were trying to access something via `angular.element`.  That's not recommended for view controllers because you have access to the DOM bindings already via the controller properties.  `angular.element` should be reserved for use in directives, and only in special cases.

I'd suggest going with *controller-as* like in your HTML and then fixing your controller like so:

```
angular
.module('Demo', ['moment-picker'])
.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   var ctrl = this 
   ctrl.onclick = function(){
      console.log(ctrl.input);
   }
}]);
```

updated plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/j1RTh7NlxADieVEnwx1q?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

its not like jquery where you select the value out of the dom.

Setting

```
  ng-model="ctrl.input"
```

sets up the two way data binding already.

What you want to do is change the js to the following

```
angular
  .module('Demo', ['moment-picker'])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    $scope.onclick = function(){
      console.log(ctrl.input);
    }

  }]);
```

Comment: I don't think that `$scope` should be used (The `onclick` function won't work in your example)

Answer (score 0):

This will console log the input.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="Demo">
      <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Angular Moment Picker - Basic demo</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//rawgit.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/master/dist/angular-moment-picker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" style="margin:30px;" ng-cloak>

    <input class="form-control"
       ng-model="ctrl.input"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
       placeholder="Select a date..."
       moment-picker="ctrl.input" id='date'>

    <button  ng-click="onclick()">submit</button>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/master/dist/angular-moment-picker.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>  




angular.module('Demo', ['moment-picker']).controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
  $scope.onclick = function(){
  console.log($scope.ctrl.input);
  }   
}]);
```